# PHP: Parse Error After Assigning Variable?

Tags: php

How come this php script is returning a parse error?

When I remove the line that assigns argv to a variable, PHP won't return a parse error. Furthermore, it says the parse error is on the print line.

```
<?php
$points = $argv[1]
print($argv[1])
?>
```

Comment: From where you are getting `$argv[1]`

Comment: It won't return a parse error because you can have one line of code without a closing semi-colon. The last line doesn't need one, but the one above it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP statements should end with `;`

```
$points = $argv[1];
                  ^
print($argv[1]);
               ^
```

Comment: Haha thanks. I'm still new to PHP.